# PHP doesn't execute in on my Nginx + php5-fpm server. Blank page

Tags: nginx, configuration, server, php

index.html works properly. But my config from sites-enabled won't work on index.php file (it doesn't even display echo, or any text before/after php tags). I have all needed dependencies installed. 
I need to execute index.php, that's linked to composer autoloader, and executes router (that must take uri from server). Thanks in advance!

This is my default file in sites-enabled:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/multisite;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mypage.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don't use SSLv3 ref: POODLE
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this structure to get your PHP-FPM working correctly

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This way you can enable the errors section and the necessary script to get your PHP-FPM up and runnig

I hope it helps.

Comment: Which one do you mean?

Comment: The default configuration file for nginx is in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define fastcgi_params SCRIPT_FILENAME.
Try adding this to you php location :

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I am not a NGINX expert but there may be a problem with your `/index.php?q=$uri&$args` try_files directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Is good for some CMS as explained in the [pitfalls page of Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

As cited:

**Note - the parameter names are different based on the package you’re
 using. For example:**

> - `q` is the parameter used by Drupal, Joomla, WordPress
> - `page` is used by CMS Made Simple